# A maximum of an integral

Tags: real-analysis

It seems that the following functions $$G(R,s)=(1-R^2)\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}
Adr da,$$ where $$A=\frac{ \sqrt{\left(\left(1+r^2\right) \cos(a+s)-2 r R \cos s\right)^2+\left(1-r^2\right)^2 \sin^2(a+s)}}{\left(1+r^2 R^2-2 r R \cos a\right)^2}$$ attains its maximum for $R=0$, if $R\in[0,1]$, however I dont have the proof.

Geometricaly, it is equivalent to find $$\sup_{z\in U}\int_{U}\left|\frac{1}{z-w}+\frac{w}{1-\bar z w}\right|du dv, \ \ w=u+iv,$$ where $U$ is the unit disk.

Comment: This integral seems to have some geometric meaning. If you have such, would you please share it?

Comment: @Fedor Petro: I made some geometric explanation.

Comment: @ Fedor Petrov. Yes, $w=u+iv$.

Comment: Written as $\sup_{z\in U}\int_{U}\left|\frac{1}{z-w}-\frac{1}{\bar z -1/w}\right|du dv$, it looks like the integral only depends  on |z| and it might just follow from some symmetry considerations that the maximum is attained at z=0.

Comment: @Wolfgang why does it depend only on $|z|$?

Comment: I don't see why the two expressions you give for $G(R,s)$ have the same values. If you write $w=\frac rR\,ze^{ia}$ with $R:=|z|$ and $r:=|w|$, then $|1-\bar zw|^2=1+r^2R^2-2rR\cos a$; but how come the denominator of the expression for $A$ is $(1+r^2R^2-2rR\cos a)^2$?

Comment: @Fedor oh sorry, maybe not... Didn't realize that $\bar z$ rotates the other way round when rotating z!

Comment: @Wolfgang By using a Mebius trasformation, the second formulation can be transformed to the fist one.

Comment: I think you meant @Iosif.

Comment: @Lira : Can you detail the use of the Möbius transformation?

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis... Take $\omega = (z-w)/(1-\bar z w)$. Then the Jacobian is $J= |\frac{1-|z|^2}{\left(-1+\omega\bar{z}\right)^2}|^2 $ and so on...